# Custom UITableViewCell AutoLayout right alignment in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

[image: <code>UIButton</code> in custom <code>UITableViewCell</code> with constraints]

All I want (actually not) is to stick `UIButton` to the right (margin) edge of the prototype custom `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView` in `UITableViewController`. I define 2 constraints: Trailing Space to: Superview (Content View) and Top Space to: Superview. Have to say that this works just fine in `UIViewController`. But when I run it on, for example, iPhone5 simulator my `UIButton` is out of the visible area. I can find it on high resolution device simulator, but shouldn't it be visible on all of them?
I've overwatched AutoLayout tutorials (inc. Stanford Course and HSE Swift Course) and all the Google, but stuck tight :(
It would be great if you could open my eyes on this `UITableViewCell` AutoLayout specificity. Thank you very much!

UPD: I'm walking through one of the tuts now and `UITableViewCell` behavior is not similar to as in the tutorial(!) It seems like cells are no longer fit in `UITableView`. I know it looks like very novice question (as I actually am), but can it be issue in Xcode7 or newly updated iOS9 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you applied constraint on your table view i.e leading trailing top & bottom.

Comment: This is it! I put `UITableView` onto the scene (view), positioning it so that it covers the whole scene. This way there was no possibility to ctrl-drag new constraint to a super view and to even realize that problem. In `UITableViewController` it works by default but not in `UIViewController`. Cell was constrained correctly but the `UITableView` ran out the right boundary. Now I pinned it via pin icon in the bottom right corner and voila! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

First clear the constraint of that button then :-

[image]

Like the above picture click right bar and upper bar then click add 2 constraint.Is this what you looking for ?

Comment: Chathuranga Silva, thank you for response, but it is still out of visible area. It looks (and I think it actually is) that constraints work fine, but the cell itself is wider than the screen width. Or `UITableView` is wider. Can it be newly iOS9 or Xcode7 issue or your layout simulates right correctly?

Comment: Delete that button , create a new button. Then do as the above. Any progress ??

Comment: Yes, I did and even one more time just for sure. And actually I did a bit more: I added Detail / Disclosure sign (checked it in at Attribute Inspector) and... I can't see it! Unless I simulate on iPad Retina. Even this signs are hidden beyond the right edge of screen (( Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for help! Problem is that the `UITableView` wasn't constrained itself to the scene and it is not obviously cause works correctly with `UITableViewController` and has to be constrained explicitly in `UIViewController`.