# ios 10 autolayout cellview out of view

Tags: autolayout, ios10, nstablecellview

New to the auto layout world, i can't seem to right align a table relative to its parent content view in the cell. Left aligning works, but when previewing on smaller screens and when running on 6s, the label is not visible/cut off.

according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729901/custom-uitableviewcell-autolayout-right-alignment-in-storyboard), the solution was to make sure the tableview was pinned correctly to the parent view controller (0,0,0,0) - but still did not fix my label.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add top, left,  right and bottom constraints to your tableView.

Also, your label has x position constraint, but how it should lay according to y coordinate? Add label top or bottom or centerVertically constraint.

And what about your redView? Set the needed constraint to it also.